# "TestNG Test" is not an option in "Run As" menu for a Maven project

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

I have  created a maven project in Eclipse IDE using Java
My file AppTest.java shows no error
I m trying to execute this file using the "TestNG Test" option in the context menu of the "Run As" option

But this option is not displayed in the context menu of the "Run As" option.

I have included a maven dependency for TestNG in **pom.xml** from *mvnrepository.com* as below

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.8.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

How do I get/ include the "TestNG Test" option in the context menu of the "Run As" option? Please help